# str.split() pass muliple delimeter one regular expression and another string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Well I am using var `str.split()` in javascript to pass multiple delimeter where one is regular express and another is string where regular expression is `/\([0-9]\)/` and string is Exception. 
How to pass both as well as I dont to replace but I just want to break the line only.

where my code

```
             var rawParts = str.split(/\([0-9]\)/), parts = [];
             for (var i = 0, len = rawParts.length, part; i < len; ++i) {
                 part = "";
                 while (rawParts[i].slice(-1) == "\\") {
                     part += rawParts[i++].slice(0, -1) + "/";
                 }
                 parts.push(part + rawParts[i]);
             }
             return parts;
         }

         var str = section_data.title;
         var val= splitPath(str).join('<br><br>');
         alert(val);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `str.split(/\([0-9]\)|(Exception)/)`

Comment: This is not working for me...

Comment: I want to use both condition in same paragraph..to work at the same time.

Comment: Can you add an example of input and output so we can know better what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this works for you ? You can add exception string with decimal delimeter as:

```
 str = str.replace(/(\(\d+\)|exception\s*\:)/gi, "<br /><br />$1");
```

Let me know, if i am getting you right and you get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that. You don't really want to split on the parenthesized numbers, but on whitespaces that are followed by the beginning of the new paragraph (i.e. numbers or "Exception").

```
var parts = str.split(/\s+(?=\(\d+\)|Exception)/g),
    val = parts.join("\n\n"); // or something
```