# how to user Javascript regex - split string without losing data and format the paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following paragraph. Now i want to manage the string in the following and i want to break the line if (1), (2) such condition occur or a specific string Exception will occur.

> The requirements of this chapter apply to the following: (1) New
>   buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies (see
>   1.4.1) (2) Additions made to, or used as, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6 and 18.1.1.4) Exception: The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions classified as occupancies other than health care
>   that are separated from the health care occupancy in accordance with
>   18.1.2.1 and conform to the requirements for the specific occupancy in accordance with Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20 through 42, as
>   appropriate.(3) Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of
>   existing health care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4) (4) Existing
>   buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to a health
>   care occupancy (see 4.6.11) Exception*: Facilities where the authority
>   having jurisdiction has determined equivalent safety has been provided
>   in accordance with Section 1.5.

In the following way:-

> The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:
>
> (1) New buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies
>   (see 1.4.1)
>
> (2) Additions made to, or used as, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6
>   and 18.1.1.4)
>
> Exception: The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions
>   classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated
>   from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1 and conform
>   to the requirements for the specific occupancy in accordance with
>   Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20 through 42, as appropriate.
>
> (3) Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of existing health
>   care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4)
>
> (4) Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy
>   to a health care occupancy (see 4.6.11) Exception*: Facilities where
>   the authority having jurisdiction has determined equivalent safety has
>   been provided in accordance with Section 1.5.

Thank you

Comment: I think he'd like to have the bulk of text in unformatted form. **that** is the problem he's trying to solve using JS.

Comment: finally somebody introduced back the problem into the question :D

Comment: @Allendar: I think your edit was quite contraproductive, as you changed the OPs input and output representation.

Comment: possible duplicate of previous question: [str.split() pass muliple delimeter one regular expression and another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896158/str-split-pass-muliple-delimeter-one-regular-expression-and-another-string) (with code, but without example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = '(1)point 1 (2) point2 exception: some exception (3) point 3'
str = str.replace(/(\(\d+\)|exception\s*\:)/gi, "<br />$1");
```

Comment: The two directly nested matching groups look really unnecessary…

Comment: Actually, you could remove them fully and use `$&` in the replacement :-)

Comment: Thanks. new thing learnt, `str.replace(/\(\d+\)|exception\:/gi, "<br />$&1")`. Please tell me it's all better now :D

Comment: No, without the `1` - see [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

Comment: oops... `str.replace(/\(\d+\)|exception\:/gi, "<br />$&")` didn't notice the `1` in front of all replacements... 
thanks a lot. 2000 visits on your profile!

Comment: THank you for the answer it really worked out for me but i forgot to mention one thing..there is still another Exception*: at the second last line which also need to be break a line where first exception where no asterik is there is in new line.I would be thankful if u can help me again...

Comment: May be `str.replace(/\(\d+\)|exception\W*\:/gi, "<br />$&")` can take care of all sorts of symbols between `exception` and `:`